# WP7 ArrayAdapter equivalent

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

I have a JSON object returned from a WCF Service, it returns two “Article” objects and looks like this:

```
{"GetArticlesResult":[{"ArticleName":"Mobile Application Development","ArticleText":"Lots of text here."},{"ArticleName":"Super Fast Development Cycle","ArticleText":"Lots more text here."}]}
```

And I can display it in a message box with this code:

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
```

What I want to do is display a list of ArticleNames in a ListBox, I will then want to link them to another page to display the ArticleText but that’s later for now.

My research has shown me that I need to use the DataContractJsonSerializer but this is where I’m stuck, all the examples seem to be a little complicated. In and Android app I would simply use an ArrayAdapter to populate something. Can I do something similar in a WP7 app?

Cheers,

Mike.

EDIT

I now have the following, how do I display the results in a ListBox?

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(e.Result));
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Article));

//put ms into a listBox here????....

[DataContract]
    public class Article
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` property of the listbox to an array/list (or `ObservableCollection` if you're going to add more items while it's displaying). If you are using a ViewModel, you can bind the ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection property on your VM and it will update automatically.

You can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (it's faster than `DataContractJsonSerializer`) to either deserialize the JSON to a strongly typed object model and bind that or you can use the same library to deserialize the JSON to a `dynamic` and then access the JSON properties from that.

If you use a strongly typed object model, you'll need to implement the changes xyzzer made to Article/ArticleList in order for it to map properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a List would work for you to deserialize/represent an array from a JSON structure. Otherwise - the question is too vague. Are you asking how to display a collection in a ListBox? Using an ItemsSource binding...

*EDIT

Try this:

```
var jsonString = "{\"GetArticlesResult\":[{\"ArticleName\":\"Mobile Application Development\",\"ArticleText\":\"Lots of text here.\"},{\"ArticleName\":\"Super Fast Development Cycle\",\"ArticleText\":\"Lots more text here.\"}]}";
var articles = Deserialize<ArticleList>(jsonString);
Debug.WriteLine(articles.GetArticlesResult.Count);

[DataContract]
public class ArticleList
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Article> GetArticlesResult { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Article
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ArticleName")]
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ArticleText")]
    public string ArticleText { get; set; }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string strData) where T : class
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    T tRet = serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as T;
    memoryStream.Dispose();
    return tRet;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I just want to be able to display the individual items on the phones screen, the values that exist in the in the unformatted JSON string above. What I display them in/with is not the issue, I just want to display them in a nice readable way for the user to see. From what I can tell above I now have the JSON in a variable of some sort named “serializer”, so what do I do with it now??? A list would be fine if that’s what I should do, I have no idea!

Comment: tRet seems to return Null and I get a InvalidDataContractException was unhandled error in your example. I think I am getting a null all along as the display I get when I run the JSON through the DataContractJsonSerializer just displays “myprojectname.ArticleList+Article”???

Comment: Weird, it works for me without any problems. Check my sample project at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1192076/PhoneApp2.zip